# How do I find iTunes library folder on Mac and Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, itunes

I made an application that parse the iTunes library to retrieve its content. It works fine in most cases but if a user moved his library somewhere else than the default iTunes folder (see: http://lifehacker.com/238296/ultranewb--how-to-move-your-itunes-library-to-an-external-drive), then I need a way to find this path.

On Mac, I was looking into ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist. There is a setting called "alis:1:iTunes Library Location" but it contains several parameters all concatenated and converted to hexadecimal.

On Windows, I found this file "C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Apple Computer\iTunes\iTunesPrefs.xml" that contains a setting "iTunes Library XML Location:1" but this one is encoded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Related (Mac-specific): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243951/how-i-locate-itunes-media-folder-location-using-com-itunes-plist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows, the `iTunes Library XML Location:1` entry in `iTunesPrefs.xml` is a [Base 64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) Unicode string, so you'll need to decode it before you can use it.  On my PC, it decodes to `C:\Documents and Settings\Emerick\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Music Library.xml`.

It should be relatively easy to decode this value using your language of choice; your platform may even provide utility libraries that make this trivial.  In C#, for example, the decoding function would look something like this:

```
static public string DecodeBase64(string encodedData)
{
  byte[] encodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
  return System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(encodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try! I saw the .pref file but wasn't sure how it was encoded.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you with the Windows stuff, but on the Mac what you're seeing in that prefs file is old-school alias handle data.  Take a look at or just use Chris Hanson's BDAlias class to convert it to a path.

http://github.com/rentzsch/bdalias

Answer (score 0):

As the others point out "alis:1:iTunes Library Location" is alias data. Here's how I find the path from the data in OS X using Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands, plistlib
from Carbon import File
from os.path import expanduser

PLIST_PATH = '~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist'
PLIST_KEY = 'alis:1:iTunes Library Location'

def resolve_path_from_alias_data( alis ):

    fs_ref = File.Alias( rawdata=alis ).FSResolveAlias( None )[0]
    file_path = fs_ref.as_pathname()
    return file_path

plist_str = commands.getoutput( '/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - "' + expanduser( PLIST_PATH ) + '"' )

plist_data = plistlib.readPlistFromString( plist_str )

alis_data = plist_data[ PLIST_KEY ].data

file_path = resolve_path_from_alias_data( alis_data )

print repr( file_path )
```

<s>Unfortunately, **iTunes no longer uses "alis:1:iTunes Library Location"** so this no longer works. Now iTunes 11 uses an entry called "RDoc:132:Documents" which seems to be *completely* different. I have posted [a similar question with the appropriate iTunes 11 details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663069/how-to-switch-to-a-new-itunes-library-location-programmatically)</s>.

Actually, my answer works just fine as of OS X 10.9.1. I'm not sure whether it stopped due to some error I made, or if Apple quietly reverted something. Either way, it's working again on my Mac.