# How i locate itunes media folder location using com.itunes.plist

Tags: macos, itunes

I need to access the media folder location of itunes thats set in iTunes-Prferencces-Advanced through com.itunes.plist.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The location of the media folder is stored under the key "alis:11345:Music Folder Location". The value stored under that key is a data blob containing the contents of an AliasHandle.  For a Cocoa wrapper to deal with alias data, take a look at the open source [BDAlias](http://github.com/rentzsch/bdalias) class.  That will let you create an alias from the data blob, and then resolve the alias to find the underlying path to which it refers.

Comment: Just noticed this old answer of mine and thought I should mention that this no longer works in more recent versions of iTunes. It looks like the media folder path now gets stored inside the iTunes Library.itl file itself, which is a proprietary data blob. So unfortunately, there's no longer an easy way to tell what the media folder location is.

Comment: Wondering if there is any solution to this issue yet, I dont even know of  a difficult way