# How to access iTunes Library both in Windows and Mac OS X

Tags: cross-platform, itunes, itunes-sdk

I would like to know how can I access to the iTunes Library information in multi-plataform way. I want to make a program that can run in both Windows and Mac OS X. Which programming language, API do you recommend? Take into account that this program will need a GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find iTunes library folder on Mac and Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962378/how-do-i-find-itunes-library-folder-on-mac-and-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using QT, which is cross platform.
Also there is something called the Cocotron, which allows you to port Cocoa apps to other platforms. Basically Cocotron is just a custom made AppKit and Foundation, which runs on both windows linux and mac.
QT works with C++, Cocotron with objective-c/objective-c++ obviously.

QT here:
http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Cocotron here:
http://www.cocotron.org/

Cocotron is really cool if you wanna know more about the possible internals of a lot of Apple's obj-c classes.